# Multiple Connection MYSQL VB.NET RowCount

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, sql-like, rowcount

I Have stack Here and does not go 
I have a loop that makes connection to database but last 2 days have problem with counting row number. And nowere to find Solution

```
    Dim row as Integer
    For i = 100 To 120
        Dim DBconn As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(My.Settings.DBConnStr)
        Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sqlcmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        sql = "SELECT Sum(D), Sum(P) FROM fin  WHERE K like '" & i.ToString & "%' "
        DBconn.Open()
        da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DBconn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DBconn.Close()
        row = dt.Rows.Count
        MsgBox("i=" & i & "    rows=" & row)
        dt.Clear()
    Next
```

MSG Box Alway tells me that the RowCount is 1, when manualy i make the query to MYSQL Diferent i Gives me Diferent Rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure how you were able to get the dataadapter to fill a datatable. It should be filling a dataset.  It should be

```
   DIM ds as New Dataset()
   da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DBconn) 
   da.Fill(ds)
   DIM rowCount = ds.Table(0).Rows.Count
```

Try this

```
   DIM rowCount = ds.Tables(0).Select().Count
```

Comment: Changed to DS and Still no Rowcount ... Maybe its why i use Loop?

Comment: Did you inspect the dataset and the table rows manually by stepping throught the code? The only reason I can see is that there is only one row as a result of the query unless the there is more than one table in the dataset. Check the ds.Tbale.Count. Make sure there is just one.

Comment: Yes There is 1 or 0 Rows , If the While Criteria Does not mach thats meen no rows , and 1 if thre is some kind of Rows